# Borderless form, VB.NET to C#?

Tags: c#

I found a code which creates a borderless form but with the frame, still on it, looks like this (Ignore the top buttons):

[image]

The code is:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim CP = MyBase.CreateParams
        CP.Style = CP.Style And Not &HC00000
        Return CP
    End Get
End Property
```

However, that code is in VB.NET. How would I be able to do it in C#? I tried using an online converter and failed.

Help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

C# version of your code would look something like this

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
         CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
         cp.Style &= ~0xc00000;
         return cp;
    }
}
```